# Constructing multiple bar chart by using only two columns from .csv file

Tags: d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I'm trying to achieve this (see image below) by using the .csv columns data(see image below). What I mean by this is representing a bar chart by using DealerCost and Retail price. The x axis is car type and y axis increments by 5,000. Currently my code shows all the columns by traversing on all of them with the for loop and thus constructing a bar chart with all the columns. (see third image below)
After trying to edit the for loop to traverse only the first 3 columns, I'm not getting any changes on the chart, and I have no idea why, would love to know what I'm doing wrong.

**Note:** I don't want to delete/change any of the .csv's file data.

**What I'm trying  to achieve:**

[image]
**My .csv file data:**

[image]

**What I've achieved so far:**

[image]

**The code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.axis .domain {
  display: none;
}
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, width])
    .paddingInner(0.1);
var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
    .padding(0.05);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
d3.csv("carsAggregated.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
  x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.CarType; }));
  x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();
  g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.CarType) + ",0)"; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); });
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));
  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text("USD Dollars ($)");
  var legend = g.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(keys.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });
  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 19)
      .attr("width", 19)
      .attr("height", 19)
      .attr("fill", z);
  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
```

this extracts the header names from the csv (dropping the first one which is the other axis - the car type). These keys are used to create the different series in the chart (here: `.data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })`)

If we only want the first two data columns (after dropping car type) we can use:

```
var keys = data.columns.slice(1).slice(0,2);
```

This will get all the headers except the first one (car type) and then drop everything other than the first two remaining columns.

Of course we could shorten that process (thanks [Gerardo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294594/constructing-multiple-bar-chart-by-using-only-two-columns-from-csv-file#comment89568562_51294785)), by using once slice:

```
var keys = data.columns.slice(1,3);
```

Either way, `keys` is still an array with the two columns we want, so we can continue as normal. [Here's](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/cdc6a54cec989d8825702ef198f002b1) a basic mock up with some hastily made fake numbers, fake car types, and a few columns.

Comment: I had a feeling that it must be envolved with this, but didn't know how to edit it properly. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: why not `var keys = data.columns.slice(1,3);`?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado ha, yes, of course, that's an oversight. Sometimes I'm too step by step rather seeing the obvious steps that can obviously be combined into one.